# NHibernate Linq group by with condition

Tags: linq, nhibernate

It seems that NHibernate Linq doesn't understand grouped .Where method conditions. I got the following code:

```
 var q = from o in session.Query<OrdreLinjeVerdier>()
     where o.OrdreLinjeReserve > 0
     group o by o.ProduktLager.ProduktLagerID into g
     select new 
     { 
         ProduktLagerID = g.Key,
         OrdreRes = g.Sum(x => x.OrdreLinjeReserve),
         OrdreResUtenSpesial = 
           g.Where(x => x.LeveringsType.LeveringsTypeID == 1)
            .Sum(x => (double?)x.OrdreLinjeReserve)
     };
```

And it just goes like this to the database:

```
select ordrelinje0_.ProduktLagerID as col_0_0_, 
    cast(sum(ordrelinje0_.OrdreLinjeReserve) as DECIMAL(19,5)) as col_1_0_,
    cast(sum(ordrelinje0_.OrdreLinjeReserve) as DOUBLE PRECISION) as col_2_0_ 
  from OrdreLinjeVerdier ordrelinje0_ 
  where ordrelinje0_.OrdreLinjeReserve>@p0 
  group by ordrelinje0_.ProduktLagerID;

  @p0 = 0
```

So basically the condition for g.Where has no effect on the SQL query.

It seems like bug or am I missing something?

Comment: It may be that the where portion of the query is evaluated on the returned data, or in additional queries. Are the actual results correct?

Comment: The result is not correct. It is 100% the same is the query result.

Comment: Isn't the 'select new' command evaluated locally, after the database query?

Comment: Linq 2 SQL does it in the query, no CASE WHEN though but not locally too. I expect it to be done in the query since I want to use this query as a source for join and expect only one database query for the whole join to be executed via nested subselect, no rocket science here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me.

After making sure this happens with the latest stable build (3.3.1 as of today), please create an issue at https://nhibernate.jira.com

Comment: I made it happen with 3.4.0.1001 also. I created it on Jira and my bug was converted to new feature :) So it just wasn't there. The Where method exists but it seems to have no effect on the output.

Comment: OK. These things take time, so I suggest that you use HQL for this query in the meantime.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev Can you provide the Jira issue number of your feature request?

Comment: It was two years ago, I can hardly remember how I got around this issue